# Which is better way of handling data Groupby/Distinct

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have big sql that scans through multiple tables having million records. After query completion, i am getting 250K records. The resultset will be saved in a staging table before getting written in files. There is a possibility  that the resultset will have duplicates.

The question is, which of the following options is better and gives a better result

1. Doing a `group by` or `distinct` before inserting into resultset into the staging table.
2. Insert duplicate records into staging table and use `distinct`/`group by` while selecting records from staging table
3. There is not much difference between 1 and 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you filter the duplicates before inserting then you are reducing the number of writes that you need to make into the staging table and, since those duplicate rows will not be in the staging table, then you are also going to reduce the number of reads from the staging table when you come to write it out to a file. So, logically, option 1 should give better performance.

However, if you are that concerned about the difference between the two then the answer has to be *"profile both methods on your system and see which is best on your hardware/tables/indexes/etc"*.